# C++ template for function call operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I tried to use template for function call operator overload as in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Apple
{
   template <typename tn> tn value ();
   template <typename tn> tn operator () ();
};

template <> int Apple::value ()
{
   return 10;
}

template <> int Apple::operator () ()
{
   return 10;
}

int main()
{
   Apple apple;
   printf("Value : %d\n", apple<int>());
   printf("Value : %d\n", apple.value<int>());   
   return 0;
}
```

While value function call in the second print does not show any error the function call operator in the first print show `expected primary-expression` error. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me know the problem thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is when invoking a templated `operator()` (second line of `main()`). In your case, you need to explicitly specify the return type, as it cannot be deduced, and the correct way of doing it is:

```
printf("Value : %d\n", apple.operator()<int>());
```

`operator()()` is a template member function that takes `()` as parameters. So, its name is `operator()`, its parameter list is `()`. Therefore, to refer to it, you need to use `apple.operator()` (its name), followed by `<int>` (template parameter), then followed by `()` (parameter list). Replace mentally the name `operator()` with `FUNCTION`, so `operator()()` is `FUNCTION()`, and you'll see the pattern. In your case, `apple<int>()` is invoking a non-template `operator()()` on a template instantiation `apple<int>` object, i.e. `apple<int>.operator()()`, which is not what you want.

Useful to define such an operator? Probably not, as it leads to ugly syntax.

---

You can achieve what you probably want by using `auto` return type in C++14, like

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Apple
{
   template <typename tn> tn value ();
   auto operator () ();
};

template <> int Apple::value ()
{
   return 10;
}

auto Apple::operator () () // not a template anymore, return type is deduced int
{
   return 10;
}

int main()
{
   Apple apple;
   printf("Value : %d\n", apple());
   printf("Value : %d\n", apple.value<int>());   
   return 0;
}
```

In this example, `auto` doesn't really shine, as you may manually specify `int` as the return type, but in more complicated declaration can be really useful.

Comment: great answer that helped thank you. can I know why the call cannot be deduced

Comment: @Dinesh, the only way for the compiler to deduce a type is to match it with some expression. In your case, at the call site there is no expression to be match against.

Comment: yes but I have specified type explicitly in both the cases and I can't understand why the error is only in the operator overload function call

Comment: What's the point of using `auto` when it's exactly equivalent to writing `int`?

Comment: @T.C. in this case absolutely no point, it may be when the return is `typename T::some_inner_type::some_mess`. I was just pointing out that OP doesn't really need a template functor operator with `void` parameters.